# Listener in multithreading only called when passed anonymously, not when declared as member

Tags: java, multithreading, listener

<sup>**Edit**</sup>

I figured it out:

The order in which I initialized the `Service` members was important! Other members (not shown in my examples) reference the `Timer` in `Runnable`s by calling the `Service` getter `getTimer()` (not shown either). In this getter the listener is registered, but not initialized yet, because it was declared/initialized *after* the other members, not *before* them. *Sigh...*

---

I have a class `Service` and an inner class `Timer` which runs in a separate thread. This timer accepts a tick listener, which is called at fixed intervals when the timer is running.

The gist of it is this:

```
public class Service {

  private Timer timer;

  Service() {
    // more to follow in code snippets below where I demonstrate the issue I am facing
  }

  private static class Timer
    implements Runnable {

    private interface TickListener {
      void onTick(Timer timer);
    }

    private TickListener tickListener;

    public void setTickListener(TickListener tickListener) {
      this.tickListener = tickListener;
    }

    public void start() {
      new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      while(keepThreadRunningCondition) {
        if(tickListener != null) {
          // to verify that Timer is actually running 
          // and tickListener is not null
          // I actually log here 
          // and the log appears just fine in all cases

          tickListener.onTick(this);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when I register the tick listener anonymously, like so:

```
class Service {

  private Timer timer;

  Service() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.setTickListener(new Timer.TickListener() {
      @Override
      void onTick(Timer timer) {
        // this gets called perfectly fine
      }
    });
  }
}
```

...the listener gets called just fine, when the timer is started.

However, when I register the tick listener as a member of my `Service` class, like so (I've tried a couple of different permutations of `public`, `final`, `volatile`, etc. as well):

```
class Service {

  private Timer timer;
  private Timer.TickListener timerTickListener = new Timer.TickListener() {
    @Override
    void onTick(Timer timer) {
      // this will NOT get called
    }
  };

  Service() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.setTickListener(timerTickListener);
  }
}
```

...the listener does *not* get called, when the timer is started.

I suspect this issue is related to multithreading, because similar setups work just fine when *not* spanning different threads, but I'm not well-versed enough in multithreading to understand exactly why this is not working.

Can you shed a light on this issue?

Does it have something to do with accessing objects by reference across different threads, perhaps? Or is it something different?

Comment: Where is the call to `timer.start()`?

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra In another method of `Service`, but I assure you, that is not the issue. It *does* get called, identically, in both cases. PS.: I verify this by logging from inside `Timer.run()`.

Comment: OK. So what does `onTick` do? Are you logging at the beginning of the call to check whether it is being called?

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra Yes, the first example runs log from inside `onTick` just fine, second example logs nothing from `onTick`. PS.: In actuality I also write to a database, inside `onTick`: first example works, second example writes nothing to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You claimed that upon registering TickListener as Service's member variable, onTicket will not get called.

This was not correct. I ran the code myself and it got called.

Here is my code,

```
package com.company;

public class Service {

    private Timer timer;
    Timer.TickListener tickListener = new Timer.TickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTick(Timer timer) {
            // this gets called perfectly fine
            System.out.println(42);
        }
    };

    Service() {
        // more to follow in code snippets below where I demonstrate the issue I am facing
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.setTickListener(tickListener);
    }

    private static class Timer
            implements Runnable {

        private interface TickListener {
            void onTick(Timer timer);
        }

        private TickListener tickListener;

        public void setTickListener(TickListener tickListener) {
            this.tickListener = tickListener;
        }

        public void start() {
            new Thread(this).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                if(tickListener != null) {
                    // to verify that Timer is actually running
                    // and tickListener is not null
                    // I actually log here
                    // and the log appears just fine in all cases

                    tickListener.onTick(this);
                }
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void foo() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Service service = new Service();
        service.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for having looked into this. I've tried to distil the problem as best as I could, from much more complicated code. I'm working on an Android project in Android Studio, and have not needed to isolate code like this before, so far. I'm too knackered right now to figure out how to run such an isolated example in Android Studio, but will do so tomorrow. But if this works just fine, as you demonstrated, then obviously the problem must lie somewhere else. I'll have to figure out what else is causing this issue then, since the issue *does* arise from anonymous to member listener. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad that helped. I ran it in IntelliJ Idea. Yeah you are right it is probably not a listener-being-member-variable issue. Try to see what else is causing action not being triggered. Try to set a breakpoint to see at a close moment if that listener is gc'ed somehow

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out: it was the order in which I declared/initialized my listener. Other `Service` members (`Runnable`, etc.) where using the `Timer` by calling the `Service` getter `getTimer()`. In this getter, I register the listener, but the listener was initialized *after* the other members, not *before*. Once I changed the order, all worked correctly. I think I need to rethink my strategies here, because it's a bit brittle this way. Anyway, thanks again, for your answer and valuable insights in your comments!